# In Drupal, how can I add the "id" attribute to a div containing fields?

Tags: html, drupal

I have a couple of fields and need anchor links but none of them contain an ID. How can I add the "id" attribute? I tried looking at the sqlite tables but alas.

I'd rather not do it with jQuery as the links might be loaded outside the same page (will be in the menu and might be clicked from, say, the front page).

Comment: Depends where the div is located? node, block, view, form, etc...

Comment: @MuhammadReda It's in a node in a panel. I've added "field--field-name.tpl.php" but so far adding id to the div just sets the IDs to the same. I cannot increment with php ($var=1, $var++). Cant even print $field_id